# Html table - td width in percentage with overflow not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table using . i have set table width as 100% .

when i set the  width of the table as 100%  and above the horizontal scrollbar doesnot work.. can some body help me to solve this. Help appreciated.

HTML:

```css
    table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%">50=50</td>
        <td style="width: 50%">50 + 50 =100</td>
        <td style="width: 30%">50 + 50 +30 =130(this td 30% need to horizontal scrollbar)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want. But the total width of the table should be `100%`. But yours are `130%`

Comment: if your using bootstrap use table-responsive class

Comment: This is not a duplicated question..Reopen this.

Comment: @konekoya I understand the total width of the table should be 100%. but here i have an requirement I need to create a table with the dynamic fields with dynamilcally set width and if the tables width goes beyond 100%. I need a horizontal scrollbar to appear. hope its clear now.

Comment: @Varsha Dhadge I am not using bootstrap here.. I am using the HTML table with dynamically set width and height

Comment: @MahalingaM SubramaniyaM Ask this question again. I have a answer, sometimes it may be worked for you.

Comment: @VSM thanks buddy. again i raised same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586173/html-tabletd-how-to-scroll-td-width-when-table-width-is-100?noredirect=1#comment90138352_51586173   Please give me a answer to this question. again thanks and  advance.

Comment: I posted there the answer for this question...Try it..Let me know if there any issues.

Comment: @VSM thanks buddy i saw your answer. your code working . but window totally scrolling. pls check  :

Comment: Apply that html code inside your div, then only that div is scrolling not the window

Comment: @VSM   //Your code:                                                                                                 table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        overflow:scroll;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

Comment: @VSM //Another Code       <style>
    .table-scroll {
        overflow: auto;
    }
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
        table td {
            min-width: 25vw;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
</style>
<div class="table-scroll">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
            <td>Column 4</td>
            <td>Column 5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

Comment: what is this code about. I have already update previous code as it matches to your requirement.

Comment: @ MahalingaM SubramaniyaM I checked that code also..That code and mine are same regarding your two problems...Both works. cheers !!!

Comment: @VSM thank you so much....