# Html table<td> - how to scroll TD width when table width is 100%?

Tags: html, css

I have create a table  using `<td>` with 5 columns. i have set table width as 100%. When i set the `<td>` width of the table as 100% and above the horizontal scrollbar does not work.

I have raised a related question already. since i did not get any answer for that question. I am again raising it here. Hope some one can help me solve this.

I have seen lot of questions regarding the size of Horizontal property given in pixels but could not see anything on %. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

I want to create something like that is shown in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJClg.png)
I have used Pixels to create it. But i need to give in %.

Previous Question Pasted by me:
link:
[Html table - td width in percentage with overflow not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554519/html-table-td-width-in-percentage-with-overflow-not-working?noredirect=1#comment90106058_51554519)

Html:

```css
table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%">Column 1</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">Column 2</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">Column 3</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">Column 4</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">Column 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have used Pixels to create it. But i need to give in %.
HTML Table Pixels and %:

```css
  table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="tableDiv" style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto; ">
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td style="min-width:250px;">Column 1</td>
                <td style="min-width:250px;">Column 2</td>
                <td style="min-width:250px;">Column 3</td>
                <td style="min-width:250px;">Column 4</td>
                <td style="min-width:250px;">Column 5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
 <br/>
    <div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="min-width:25%;">Column 1</td>
                <td style="min-width:25%;">Column 2</td>
                <td style="min-width:25%;">Column 3</td>
                <td style="min-width:25%;">Column 4</td>
                <td style="min-width:25%;">Column 5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? There's no need to scroll horizontally, because your content fits into the container without any overflow... Are you looking to set a minimum width for each cell so that column 5 isn't 'compacted'? Also, note that percentages are relative to the immediate parent. Not only do you need a fixed unit of measurement at some point, but each of the ancestors will need a percentage `width` in order for the descendant(s) to inherit it as well.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51586448/3516008

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS Unit `vw`, see docs: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

> vw = Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport^
>
> ^ Viewport = the browser window size. If the viewport is 50cm wide, 1vw = 0.5cm.

Then make your `td` as min-width `25vw`

```
 table td {
     min-width: 25vw;
     ...
 }
```

In order to have the horizontal scroll on the table only you can wrap it and then apply the overflow...
Html:

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
  [...]
  </table>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.table-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```css
.table-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}
table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

table td {
            min-width: 25vw;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td>Column 1</td>
          <td>Column 2</td>
          <td>Column 3</td>
          <td>Column 4</td>
          <td>Column 5</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad its works. Please, read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

```css
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div style="width: 100vw; overflow:scroll;">
   <table style="width: 130vw;">
      <tr>
          <td style="width: 50vw">50=50</td>
          <td style="width: 50vw">50 + 50 =100</td>
          <td style="width: 30vw">50 + 50 +30 =130(this td 30% need to horizontal scrollbar)</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

This answer for your previous question. try this.

Comment: I have update this code as it matches to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You should try instead to use min-width rather than width alone.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="min-width: 25%">Column 1</td>
        <td style="min-width: 25%">Column 2</td>
        <td style="min-width: 25%">Column 3</td>
        <td style="min-width: 25%">Column 4</td>
        <td style="min-width: 25%">Column 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or if you were trying to get the scrollbar you could increase the table width

```
table {
        width: 125%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="min-width: 25%">Column 1</td>
        <td style="min-width: 25%">Column 2</td>
        <td style="min-width: 25%">Column 3</td>
        <td style="min-width: 25%">Column 4</td>
        <td style="min-width: 25%">Column 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tried ur solution but the coloumns go beyond the table area. and the scroll bar doesnot appear for the table.

Comment: What do you mean by scroll bar for table?

Comment: Try this instead: table {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    td {
      min-width: 200px;
    } 
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Comment: I have used Pixels to create it. But i need to give in %.

Comment: @MahalingaMSubramaniyaM So use `vw` unit then, it is based on the % of the viewport. See my answer.